# How to add hboxes and vboxes code to notebook tabs in python gtk

Tags: python, webkit, pygtk

I am doing a small RSS news app for ubuntu. I have created a notebook using

```
notebook=gtk.Notebook()
win.add(notebook)
label1=gtk.Label()
label1.set_text("one")
notebook.append_page(label1,label1)
```

And I have this codee with hbox,vbox and  a scroller.

```
box1=gtk.VBox()
win.add(box1)
box2=gtk.HBox()
box1.pack_start(box2)
addressbar=gtk.Entry()
box2.pack_start(addressbar)
gobutton=gtk.Button("GO")
box2.pack_start(gobutton)
gobutton.connect('clicked',gob)    
scroller=gtk.ScrolledWindow()
box1.pack_start(scroller)
web=webkit.WebView()
scroller.add(web)
```

How to add the second code into the notebook tab in the first code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put `box1` into the current Notebook page instead of putting it into `win`.

```
label1 = gtk.Label("one")
box1 = gtk.VBox()
notebook = gtk.Notebook()
notebook.append_page(box1, label1)
win.add(notebook)

box2 = gtk.HBox()
box1.pack_start(box2)
#etc
```

BTW, I don't see you calling the `.show` method on your widgets; I assume you're calling `win.show_all` once you've created them all.